# Delete rows group by one column and all rows have nan value in an other column in panda / python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to group by one column (`id`) and check if all the values of an other column `day` are 'nan', and in this case delete all the rows corresponding.

I was going like this :

```
output = entry.iloc[entry.groupby['id'].day.isnull()]
```

but it's not working...

```
entry = pd.DataFrame([ [1,],[1,],[1,],[1,],[2,3],[2,],[2,4]],columns=['id','day'])
output = pd.DataFrame([[2,3],[2,],[2,4]],columns=['id','day'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` ,`transform`,and `count`

```
entry.loc[entry.groupby('id')['day'].transform('count').nonzero()]
Out[154]: 
   id  day
4   2  3.0
5   2  NaN
6   2  4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use groupby with filter

```
entry.groupby('id').day.filter(lambda g: g.notnull().sum()!=0)

4    3.0
5    NaN
6    4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `groupby` and followed by `filter` to check those group of `id` that has sum of days greater than 0.

```
entry.groupby('id').filter(lambda group: group.day.sum()>0)
```

Result:

```
   id  day
4   2  3.0
5   2  NaN
6   2  4.0
```